# HTC EVO 3D not appearing on Mac OSX adb

Tags: adb, htc, macos, htc-evo-3d

I am having a funky issue connecting my HTC EVO 3D (Running 4.0.3) to my MacBook Pro (OSX 10.9.1). I have connected this phone using `adb` and `Android Studio` for development, using the same cord, same phone, and operating system on a different computer.

The EVO is in debug mode, tried swapping out cables, swapping ports, restarting computer multiple times, restarting phone etc. The phone will mount as a disk, but can not be discovered by `adb` in any connection mode.

This leaves me to believe that either my USB ports on my MacBook are messed up, which I have followed instructions to reseting my [SMC](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964) and [PRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379), which lead to nothing. So then I thought it was possibly a corrupt ADB, so I went ahead and reinstalled the Android SDK This lead to a few hours wasted, but was feeling confident this would solve my problems. Unfortunately it did not, does anyone have any suggestions?

**Edit:** To add to the confusion, I can get the EVO to mount as a storage device, and upload an `apk` for development, but this is not very helpful if I have to transfer the file manually every time I want to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After months of not being able to debug through ADB, I've figured it out. According to [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6027013/1858217), the program `EasyTetherUSBEthernet` can cause problems with ADB.

Running this in terminal, with a reboot fixed all my problems.

```
sudo kextunload -v /System/Library/Extensions/EasyTetherUSBEthernet.kextv
```

If you need to use `EasyTetherUSBEthernet` you can reload it using:

```
sudo kextload -v /System/Library/Extensions/EasyTetherUSBEthernet.kext
```